# Calculate the price based on height and width

Tags: prestashop

I need to make a module that allow the user to enter width and height  , and then it should calculate the price based on the height and width .
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's say that you want to do it on the product ID N° 1 from the product page :
first add two inputs fields in your product.tpl ( or in your module.tpl called in product.tpl)

```
<input name="height"><br>
<input name="width">
```

now you need to get it in your module.php to change the price dynamicly :

```
$id_product = 1;    
$newPrice = 0;
$height = Tools::getValue('height');
$width = Tools::getValue('width');

//Price rules (change with your rules)
if($height > 10 && $width > 10) $newPrice = 10;

    $specific_price = new SpecificPrice();
    $specific_price->price = $newPrice;
    $specific_price->id_cart = (int) $this->context->cart->id;
    $specific_price->id_shop = 0;
    $specific_price->id_shop_group = 0;
    $specific_price->id_currency = 0;
    $specific_price->id_country = 0;
    $specific_price->id_group = 0;
    $specific_price->id_customer = (int) $this->context->customer->id;
    $specific_price->id_product = (int)$id_product;
    $specific_price->id_product_attribute = 0;
    $specific_price->from_quantity = 1;
    $specific_price->reduction = 0;
    $specific_price->reduction_type = 'amount';
    $specific_price->from = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
    $specific_price->to = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
    $specific_price->add();
```

and if you want add it to cart

```
    $cart->id_lang = (int)($this->context->cookie->id_lang);
    $cart->id_currency = (int)($this->context->cookie->id_currency);
    $cart->updateQty($qte, $id_product);
```

and after order is done you put the normal price, so override the orderConfirmation controller in override/controllers/front/OrderConfirmationController.php:

```
class OrderConfirmationController extends OrderConfirmationControllerCore
{
    public $ssl = true;
    public $php_self = 'order-confirmation';
    public $id_cart;
    public $id_module;
    public $id_order;
    public $reference;
    public $secure_key;

    public function getPriceBack($id_product){

        $normalPrice = Product::getPriceStatic($id_product);

        $specific_price = new SpecificPrice();
        $specific_price->price = $normalPrice;
        $specific_price->id_cart = (int) $this->context->cart->id;
        $specific_price->id_shop = 0;
        $specific_price->id_shop_group = 0;
        $specific_price->id_currency = 0;
        $specific_price->id_country = 0;
        $specific_price->id_group = 0;
        $specific_price->id_customer = (int) $this->context->customer->id;
        $specific_price->id_product = (int)$id_product;
        $specific_price->id_product_attribute = 0;
        $specific_price->from_quantity = 1;
        $specific_price->reduction = 0;
        $specific_price->reduction_type = 'amount';
        $specific_price->from = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
        $specific_price->to = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
        $specific_price->add();

    }

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        $this->id_cart = (int)(Tools::getValue('id_cart', 0));
        $is_guest = false;

        /* get normal price back */
        $id_product = 1;
        self::getPriceBack($id_product);

        /* check if the cart has been made by a Guest customer, for redirect link */
        if (Cart::isGuestCartByCartId($this->id_cart)) {
            $is_guest = true;
            $redirectLink = 'index.php?controller=guest-tracking';
        } else {
            $redirectLink = 'index.php?controller=history';
        }

        $this->id_module = (int)(Tools::getValue('id_module', 0));
        $this->id_order = Order::getOrderByCartId((int)($this->id_cart));
        $this->secure_key = Tools::getValue('key', false);
        $order = new Order((int)($this->id_order));
        if ($is_guest) {
            $customer = new Customer((int)$order->id_customer);
            $redirectLink .= '&id_order='.$order->reference.'&email='.urlencode($customer->email);
        }
        if (!$this->id_order || !$this->id_module || !$this->secure_key || empty($this->secure_key)) {
            Tools::redirect($redirectLink.(Tools::isSubmit('slowvalidation') ? '&slowvalidation' : ''));
        }
        $this->reference = $order->reference;
        if (!Validate::isLoadedObject($order) || $order->id_customer != $this->context->customer->id || $this->secure_key != $order->secure_key) {
            Tools::redirect($redirectLink);
        }
        $module = Module::getInstanceById((int)($this->id_module));
        if ($order->module != $module->name) {
            Tools::redirect($redirectLink);
        }
    }
}
```

after the order is done you have to empty the cart with id_product and delete rule in dbb :

```
    $this->context->cart->deleteProduct(1);

    Db::getInstance()->execute('DELETE FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'specific_price WHERE  id_customer='.(int)$this->context->customer->id);
```

it s just an example and can not use without variables tests and maybe put constante for your product id concerned, hope it helps

Comment: in order to change the price dynamicaly , should i update updateQty function in cart.php ?

Comment: here's the problem i'm facing : 
let's say we have a product with the base price : 100$
the user orders a product with custom height and width , and let's say the price becomes 100$ +20 $ = 120$ 
and since the new price is calculated and added with the specific price , on the next order the base price will become 120$ , and i couldnt find a way to make the price go back to the original amount

Comment: it s a specific price for the customer, so at your place i ll just do the samething in the other side, with $specific_price->price equal to the real price when order is done

Comment: I'm not able to add another specific price if the first one already exists ?

Comment: you right, in my case i empty the cart and delete rule in dbb, i ll complete my answer

Comment: dont you think it'll be easier to delete the specific price in order confirmation ?

Comment: Yes because order is done so you can delete the spe ific rule